# Adding roles when level up

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to add a role every time a user levels up.
But, I am getting an error: TypeError: add_roles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'role'. This is the code i have right now:

```
if users[f'{user.id}']['level'] == 2:
    role_id = 833924720617062430
    await user.add_roles(user, role = role_id)
```

Comment: Im assuming `user` is a discord.Member instance?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

member.add_roles(), takes just the roles as the parameter, not role ids or member instances.

```py
# getting the role
role = user.guild.get_role(role_id)
if role is None:
   print('invalid role id')
await user.add_roles(role)
```

Note: this only works if `user` is a [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member) instance

### References:

- [get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)